# If I have a lot of money, I would buy the house. vs. If I had a lot of money, I would buy the house.(indicative vs. subjunctive)

Tags: subjunctives, if

> If I have a lot of money, I would buy the house.

> If I had a lot of money, I would buy the house.

What's the difference of the two sentences and which one is more widely used among native English speakers?

Comment: I don't see any reasons someone would downvote this question unless they really want to discourage us as English learners. I hope someday the vote system for original poster will be removed. The moderator can just delete inappropriate questions only. Anyway, I'm trying to help if that's ok. I've never seen the first sentence, and I think the second one is correct. You might want to say: *If I have a lot of money, I will buy the house* in my view, this sentence is like a promise that may be done in the future by the speaker, whereas the second is more imaginative which is not necessarily real.

Comment: @user516076 - partly because this is the same question as https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309281/if-i-am-female-vs-if-i-were-female-indicative-vs-subjunctive just using a different example. It again shows zero research.

Comment: The quality of the question does not necessarily need research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence, the speaker doesn't express any opinion on the truth or falsehood of the condition.  You would not often use this exact expression, as it would be unusual for you to not know how much money you have.

You could say, for example.

> If I have my credit card, I will buy you a drink.  Let me see if I put it in my wallet this morning.

The speaker doesn't know if they have a credit card or not.  It is natural to use the "will" rather than "would" in the conclusion.

On the other hand, the form

> If I had lots of money...

introduces a hypothetical. This means that "I don't have lots of money, but let's imagine..."  You correctly use "would" in the conclusion.

So

> If I had my credit card, I would buy you a drink. But I can't get you a drink tonight.

You can investigate "first, second, and third conditionals" for a simplified analysis of English conditional forms.

Comment: I believe I have somewhat a sound knowledge in a subjunctive mood but I want to feel the responses from you guys to feel about English itself based on my English knowledge and intuition because I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: The first rule of "subjunctive" is "don't use subjunctive".  The reason for this rule is that most situations in which a verb form was derived from an Old English subjunctive, are no longer distinguishable from the indicative.  If you were speaking old English you might be using a past subjunctive here.  But in modern English, only vestiges remain.  I would not call "if I had lots of money" an example of the subjective.  It is indistinguishable from a past tense.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are correct, but mean different things.

- "If I have a lot of money, I would buy the house," is a wish for the future. It's possible, perhaps likely, you plan to buy it.
- "If I had a lot of money, I would buy the house," is more "wishful thinking". Since, at present,  you *don't* have the money, you're not actually going to buy it.

Comment: Short but have a strong insight.